# what does ref means mongooose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i was reading mongoosejs documentations and get on populate method and populate with 'ref' is some kinda obscure to understand i also saw many stackoverflow questions , MDN but nobody spent much time to explain that

```
var personSchema = Schema({
_id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
name: String,
 age: Number,
 stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
 author: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' },
 title: String,
 fans: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Person' }]
 });

 var Story = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
 var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

so here is one example and the docs are saying that ref: references which model should we use, but in this case author has ref to person and it's type is objectId and how can it store whole schema (_id, name ,age,stories)  and same on stories property, how can it store whole  schema (in mongoose language 'document') .

```
Story.
findOne({ title: 'Casino Royale' }).
populate('author').
exec(function (err, story) {
if (err) return handleError(err);
console.log('The author is %s', story.author.name);
// prints "The author is Ian Fleming"
});
```

here as i analysed this code finds field of title in story model then it gets author property in story model too  and then gets name from second schema. as code shows,author has referenced person model but as i admited it's type is objectId and how can it store whole schema (_id, name ,age,stories)

if someone can explain this in
 more details they will help many of guys who did not get it like me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ref` basically means that `mongoose` would store the `ObjectId` values and when you call `populate` using those ObjectIds would fetch and fill the documents for you. So in this case:

```
stories: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
```

An `ObjectId` for the Story would be only stored in the **Person** `stories` array and when you call on `populate('stories')` mongoose would go and do another query to find and match all the `ObjectId` and return you the actual `Stories` objects.

So `ref` just tells mongoose that you want to store there a reference to another model and at some point you want to `populate` those and get the full blown model by that reference.

In a sense it is nothing more than a `foreign` key to another collection by which you fetch the actual document when `populate` is called.

Here is the code broken down:

```
Story.findOne({ title: 'Casino Royale' })  // <-- filter on title
  // once a story is found populate its `author` with full author document 
  // instead of the `ObjectId` stored by the `ref`
  .populate('author')
  // execute the current pipeline
  .exec(function (err, story) { // handle the resulting record
    if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log('The author is %s', story.author.name);
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: "An ObjectId for the Story would be only stored in the Person stories array" 

what does tell mongoose to store that Story's objectid  especially ind the stories property and  in storySchema there is 2 different id defined? , sorry it is most obscure thing in mongoose i think

Comment: Well in relational databases you have a foreign key concept. That is exactly the same thing. You store a foreign key (ObjectId) so you can "relate" to the other table/collection of documents when you do `populate`

Comment: so u mean stories, author and fans have same id because of ref ?

Comment: person has collection of stories Ids, story has a collection of person Ids, and fan also has a collection of person Ids. Those ids could very well be the same if a person is both the author and a fan of a story.

Comment: so if we sum the last code i posted (Story.findone()) 
first it finds field with title in Story model, then it populates author, and that means it get author property in Story model and then it queries author name but how can it have connection with Story, because _id  property from personSchema and author property from storySchema has same values ?
if u are bothered dont answer as you wish or move to chat if u want

Comment: please check this

Comment: i think i analysed: the property which have ref to other model, when we populate that property we can use the model properties which we referenced to the first property